# Error while trying to classify new instance using Java with Weka-No output instance format defined

Tags: java, classification, weka

I am trying to use Weka in my project to classify text documents using a Naïve Bayes classifier. I found the two classes below on [this site](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/a-simple-text-classifier-in-java-with.html).

The first class `MyFilteredLearner` builds, trains, evaluates, and saves the classifier to disk, this all works fine.

The second class `MyFilteredClassifier` loads the single text string from a text file and makes it into an instance successfully. It also restores the classifier from disk. What it fails to do is to classify the instance with the method `classify()`, it instead returns the exception message ‘No output instance format defined’.

I have spend ages searching for an answer, have tried installing the developer and stable versions of Weka, but still get the same issue.

Does anybody know what is incorrect in the code or needs to be added/done differently? The file details and code are as follows:

**ARFF file (spam.ARFF) used to train the classifier:**

```
@relation sms_test

@attribute spamclass {spam,ham}
@attribute text String

@data
ham,'Go until jurong point, crazy.. Available only in bugis n great world la e buffet...Cine there got amore wat...'
etc……………………………………………………………………
```

**Single line text file (`toClassify.txt`) for the new instance:**

```
this is spam or not, who knows?
```

**Code of `MyFilteredLearner`:**

```
public class MyFilteredLearner {
    Instances trainData;
    StringToWordVector filter;
    FilteredClassifier classifier;

    public void loadDataset(String fileName) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            ArffReader arff = new ArffReader(reader);
            trainData = arff.getData();
            System.out.println("===== Loaded dataset: " + fileName + " =====");
            reader.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem found when reading: " + fileName);
        }
    }

    public void learn() {
        try {
            trainData.setClassIndex(0);
            classifier = new FilteredClassifier();
            filter = new StringToWordVector();
            filter.setAttributeIndices("last");
            classifier.setFilter(filter);
            classifier.setClassifier(new NaiveBayes());
            classifier.buildClassifier(trainData);
            System.out.println("===== Training on filtered (training) dataset done =====");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem found when training");
        }
    }

    public void evaluate() {
        try {
            trainData.setClassIndex(0);
            filter = new StringToWordVector();
            filter.setAttributeIndices("last");
            classifier = new FilteredClassifier();
            classifier.setFilter(filter);
            classifier.setClassifier(new NaiveBayes());
            Evaluation eval = new Evaluation(trainData);
            eval.crossValidateModel(classifier, trainData, 4, new Random(1));
            System.out.println(eval.toSummaryString());
            System.out.println(eval.toClassDetailsString());
            System.out.println("===== Evaluating on filtered (training) dataset done =====");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Problem found when evaluating");
        }
    }

    public void saveModel(String fileName) {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
            out.writeObject(classifier);
            System.out.println("Saved model: " + out.toString());
            out.close();
            System.out.println("===== Saved model: " + fileName + "=====");
            } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem found when writing: " + fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

**Code of `MyFilteredClassifier`:**

```
public class MyFilteredClassifier {
    String text;
    Instances instances;
    FilteredClassifier classifier;  
    StringToWordVector filter;

    public void load(String fileName) {
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line;
            text = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        text = text + " " + line;
                }
            System.out.println("===== Loaded text data: " + fileName + " =====");
            reader.close();
            System.out.println(text);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem found when reading: " + fileName);
        }
    }

    public void makeInstance() {
        FastVector fvNominalVal = new FastVector(2);
        fvNominalVal.addElement("spam");
        fvNominalVal.addElement("ham");
        Attribute attribute1 = new Attribute("class", fvNominalVal);
        Attribute attribute2 = new Attribute("text",(FastVector) null);
        FastVector fvWekaAttributes = new FastVector(2);
        fvWekaAttributes.addElement(attribute1);
        fvWekaAttributes.addElement(attribute2);
        instances = new Instances("Test relation", fvWekaAttributes,1);           
        instances.setClassIndex(0);
        DenseInstance instance = new DenseInstance(2);
        instance.setValue(attribute2, text);
        instances.add(instance);
        System.out.println("===== Instance created with reference dataset =====");
        System.out.println(instances);
    }

    public void loadModel(String fileName) {
        try {
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fileName));
            Object tmp = in.readObject();
            classifier = (FilteredClassifier) tmp;
            in.close();
            System.out.println("===== Loaded model: " + fileName + "=====");
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Problem found when reading: " + fileName);
        }
    }

    public void classify() {
        try {
            double pred = classifier.classifyInstance(instances.instance(0));
            System.out.println("===== Classified instance =====");
            System.out.println("Class predicted: " + instances.classAttribute().value((int) pred));
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyFilteredLearner c = new MyFilteredLearner();
        c.loadDataset("spam.ARFF");
        c.learn();
        c.evaluate();
        c.saveModel("spamClassifier.binary");
        MyFilteredClassifier c1 = new MyFilteredClassifier();
        c1.load("toClassify.txt");
        c1.loadModel("spamClassifier.binary");
        c1.makeInstance();
        c1.classify();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you change the code from the blog's GitHub repository in one detail and it is the cause of your error:

```
c.learn();
c.evaluate();
```

vs

```
c.evaluate();
c.learn();
```

The `evaluate()` method resets the classifier with the line:

```
classifier = new FilteredClassifier();
```

but doesn't build a model. The actual evaluation uses a copy of the passed classifier, so the original classifier (the one in your class) remains untrained.

```
// weka/classifiers/Evaluation.java (method: crossValidateModel)
Classifier copiedClassifier = Classifier.makeCopy(classifier);
copiedClassifier.buildClassifier(train);
```

So you first build your model, but then overwrite it when evaluating it and then save the uninitialized model. Switch them around so you train it directly before saving it to a file, then it works.

Comment: Hi Sentry, there is a link above. Thanks for looking into this, you has solved the problem!

Comment: @tippler2000 Oops, my bad. Sorry for the wrong accusation, removing it now

Comment: Thank you @Sentry for your useful answer, I want to ask about makeCopy method that is not available. What is current method replace it.

Comment: @F505 I don't understand. But it would be better for you to make this a full question, I'm happy to answer that then.

Comment: As what you mentioned in the answer: (Classifier copiedClassifier = Classifier.makeCopy(classifier);) in my code the method is not recognized by the compiler?! not sure why

Comment: @F505 Please post this as its own question, the comments are not a good way to ask or answer questions.